# Permission denied when Settings gvm on Mac

Tags: macos, grails, user-permissions, gvm

i install gvm bash at  a MAC PC,via following :

```
curl -s get.gvmtool.net | bash
```

When i run this command :

```
gvm install grails 2.2.3
```

i get the following error message :

```
mkdir :/Users/abdennour/.gvm/archives Permission denied
```

**UPDATE:**

Known that , `sudo gvm` does not work and it return :

```
gvm  command not found
```

Comment: you didn't run any of those commands with sudo did you?

Comment: What does `ls -la ~/.gvm` show?

Answer (score 0):

You must uninstall all and re install  GVM. Then run

```
gvm install grails
```